# What is tenant property in new flutter firebase authentication package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I was checking the firebase authentication package for flutter and it has a property called tenantId . But i dont know what's the use of it. All it says is.

> The current user's tenant ID.
> This is a read-only property, which indicates the tenant ID used to sign in the current user. This is null if the user is signed in from the parent project.

But how to use it is the question and where to use it? Is the main question.
Your help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the relatively new multi-tenant feature of Firebase Authentication.  You can read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/multi-tenancy-authentication) and [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/multi-tenant-applications-with-firebase-and-google-cloud-4d0d02b7d859).

Comment: Any recommendation on how to actually use multi tenacy with flutter? I seems like setting a tenant id is not supported. Is the only possibility to call a server-side function with credentials and return a token to sign in a user?

Comment: @Jonas There is an open issue here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1584